# Grid loaded from JSON file its works in IE but not able to load in fireFox?

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I am using ExtJS3.3.1 and try to load a Grid from file which contains a JSON Object.
It will work fine in IE loads grid with data but not works in Firefox.
here is simple code It doesn't give any error and warnning.

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({

    url: 'http://localhost/Vaishali/src/survey.html',

    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'data',
        id: 'appeId',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }, [{
        name: 'appeId',
        mapping: 'appeId'
    }, {
        name: 'survId',
        mapping: 'survId'
    }, {
        name: 'location',
        mapping: 'location'
    }, {
        name: 'surveyDate',
        mapping: 'surveyDate'
    }, {
        name: 'surveyTime',
        mapping: 'surveyTime'
    }, {
        name: 'inputUserId',
        mapping: 'inputUserId'
    }])
});

store.load();

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        header: "appeId",
        width: 60,
        dataIndex: 'appeId',
        sortable: true
    }, {
        header: "survId",
        width: 60,
        dataIndex: 'survId',
        sortable: true
    }, {
        header: "location",
        width: 60,
        dataIndex: 'location',
        sortable: true
    }, {
        header: "surveyDate",
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'surveyDate',
        sortable: true
    }, {
        header: "surveyTime",
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'surveyTime',
        sortable: true
    }, {
        header: "inputUserId",
        width: 80,
        dataIndex: 'inputUserId',
        sortable: true
    }],
    width: 540,
    height: 200
});
```

so can u please tell me why this happens.
oops
when I added the event onload and check the exception in mozilla firefox it will show exception in that status code show 0 and text "connection Failure'.
but in IE it will give proper connection and result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect you're not loading the page from `http://localhost/` as well, so you're running afoul of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). IE's more forgiving than it strictly speaking should be.

Comment: ya.i am not running that file from server thats the problem.now properly working